# How to send cloud message 10 minutes before start in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, web-applications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm programming an event-based web app using javascript and firebase. What I want is 10 minutes before the start of the event a cloud message to the organiser.
I suppose that I must add the notification immediately after the reservation has been added to the database but I have no idea what this "thing" must contain.

```
function AddEvent(){
//Event Added to firebase
//---Something to set a message with eventtime-10 minutes
}
```

I really appreciated it if someone can help me and also expand my knowledge.

Kind regards

Comment: You can do a firebase function that executes every minute, searching for events starting 10 minutes later, then inside it, you do what you want..

Comment: Does this also works when you don't use the app in the background?

Comment: yup, is executed on the firebase servers, not on the app